# Directory path in S3 for particular folder name in AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

For example, s3 has three folders:

```
folder/folder1/subfolder1
folder/folder2/subfolder1
folder/folder2/subfolder2
```

So I need path for all subfolder1. Expected answer:

```
folder/folder2/subfolder1
folder/folder1/subfolder1
```

Comment: Which language are you using? What have you tried so far -- can you show us your code? What problem are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

According to this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property,

1. You can use the ListObjectsV2 method to retrieve the directory paths.
2. Then filter the objects to get only the directories with the specified name

Answer (score 0):

```
List<S3ObjectSummary> listS3ObjectSummary= s3Local.listObjectsV2(amazonS3URI.getBucket()).getObjectSummaries();
List<String> listPath= new ArrayList<>();
listS3ObjectSummary.forEach(e->{e.getBucketName().contains("subfolder1");listPath.add(e.getBucketName());});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).